# $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left|\frac1n-\frac2n+\frac3n-\frac4n+\ldots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac nn\right|$

Tags: calculus, limits

May I ask why, when calculating this limit, the marked place should have the number $4$ instead of $2$ ?

[image]

Comment: @JMoravitz It's a solved example from the textbook, but it could be wrong

Comment: What *exact* line do you see in the textbook that suggests there should be a $4$?  Perhaps there is something else that is different as well which makes up for the difference.  Alternatively of course it could just be a typo.

Comment: @JMoravitz there is exactly the same procedure except for those sums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in an earlier line:

$\begin{align}
1&-2+3-4+\ldots+(n-1)-n=\\
&=1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)+n-2\big(2+4+\ldots+n\big)=\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk-2\cdot\color{red}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}k\end{align}$

You have a $2$ from the previous line, and you took a $\color{red}{2}$ as a factor when you wrote the sum: $$2+4+\ldots+n=\color{red}{2}\left(1+2+\ldots+\frac n2\right)$$

Comment: I had missed that as well.  Good eye.

Comment: Yep, didn't realize that at all, thanks :)

Comment: @Martin88 You are welcome. Please use mathjax for the posts. It's easier to read